# How do you add custom syntax highlighting for an additional language to Light Table?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, lighttable

Do you need to write a plugin for this or can you do it e.g. with the `user.behaviors` file?

Where can I find a tutorial and comprehensive documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

LightTable uses CodeMirror for syntax highlighting.

If the language you want is one of [CodeMirrors existing modes](http://codemirror.net/mode/index.html) (and it's in the version of the node module that your version of LightTable is using) then you should be able to use the `set-syntax` command (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> then type "syntax" to find it) to apply it to the current editor. You can add the following to your `user.behaviors` file to associate the syntax with a given file extension:

```clj
[:files :lt.objs.files/file-types [{:exts [:eg],
                                    :mime "text/x-example",
                                    :name "Example",
                                    :tags [:editor.example]}]]
```

If a CodeMirror mode is not available, you'll first need to write one. Here are some docs on [Writing CodeMirror Modes](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi).

Comment: There is a closing square bracket missing at the end of your example :)

Comment: Well spotted @Shautieh, thanks! I've corrected the example. I guess I copied it from a longer list.

Comment: You're welcome @RobinGower. I found it out easily as I was trying to use it to add ocaml syntax highlighting to lighttable :) For the record, it's like this :
    [:files :lt.objs.files/file-types [{:name "Eliom" :exts [:eliom] :mime "text/x-ocaml" :tags [:editor.ocaml]}] ]

Answer (score 0):

@RobinGower's answer works for me, eg for Jade syntax highlighting add `[:files :lt.objs.files/file-types [{:name "jade" :exts [:jade] :mime "text/x-jade" :tags [:editor.jade]}] ]` to the `user.behaviors` file

@mydoghasworms - have you already seen these pages?

- [LightTable FAQ page](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/wiki/FAQ)
- [getting started](http://docs.lighttable.com/tutorials/full/)

I found a few helpful things on both.